# Why doesn't TransactionScope start a transaction for my following SQL commands

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I set up a using block for a `TransactionScope` at the beginning of an ASP.NET action. Somewhere w/i the block I execute a function that both creates a using block for a `SqlCommand` and w/i that a using block for my `SqlConnection`.

The blocks for the command and connection open and close as the function is re-used but all w/i the `TransactionScope` using block. Eventually I call `scope.Complete()` and when leaving the `TransactionScope` using block I get an exception saying that no transaction was started that can be committed. In debugging I find that in fact all database calls are just happening w/o a transaction.

Based off the documentation its seeming like the generation of the `TransactionScope` should be the generation of the transaction, OR, at least that the first time I open any database connection that a transaction should begin because it's w/i the transaction scope block. However this is not the case and I'm unsure why this is.

I actually had this working fine at one point and then all of a sudden, it was not working. So there's something that I did that caused it but I have no idea what it was as the section this was implemented in was completed long ago.

Here's some code:

Starting the transactionScope

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        LegacyDataManager.Start();

        //*******************Replace W/ Controller Logic*********************
        ViewBag.Message = "Finish";
        ...
        ...
        ...
        LegacyDataManager.Commit();
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
    finally
    {
        LegacyDataManager.Stop();
    }
}
```

Call to code that executes database update

```
var theApproval = LegacyDataManager.PrepareForUpdate(Constants.ObjectApproval, row["objectInstance"].ToString(), row["sourceServer"].ToString());
                                    theApproval.write("approvalaction", Request.Form[val].ToString().Substring(0, 1));
                                    theApproval.write("approvaldate", Data_Legacy.getAodDateTimeNow());
                                    theApproval.saveObject();
```

The database query execution

```
Data.executeSP("sp_Object_InsertData", SearchNew.generateSQLParameterString("ObjectType", "ObjectInstance", "Parameter", "ParameterValue", "SourceServer"),
                                                SearchNew.generateSQLParameterString(
                                                ObjectType,
                                                ObjectInstance.ToString(),
                                                theNametext,
                                                Regex.Replace(thetheVal, @"\'", "\'\'").Trim(),
                                                SourceServer));

public static DataTable executeSP(string storedProc, SqlParameter[] parms = null, bool gatherParams = true, int commandTimeout = 0)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        if (commandTimeout != 0)
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = storedProc;

        handleParameters(cmd.Parameters, storedProc, parms, gatherParams);

        using (SqlConnection conn = Data.getConnection("AOD"))
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
                conn.Open();

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

The good news is that this can just be removed but the bad news is that it creates an annoying programming environment where the XML data files this system is based don't get updated during an error but the updated SQL data that is mirrored out to is retained... Don't ask why that's how it is... it just is.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I had added a try/catch block around a function that ran a Stored procedure because the data being passed in would sometimes need the function and sometimes not (and thus fail, hence the try catch). Unfortunately when the db call failed the transaction associated w/ the TransactionScope was dropped and the try catch kept the program going.

I removed the the try catch block and replaced it w/ a check on the data passed into the function before determining whether or not to execute the Stored Procedure and now it is once again operating properly.

TL;DR - Check to see if any database calls are failing w/i the transactionScope as it might lead to dropping of the transaction.

Comment: Your TL;DR is incorrect - there's nothing wrong with try..catch inside a `TransactionScope`. It's inaccurate to say that they should be avoided as there are valid reasons to use them.

Comment: @Fermin How can you say that when the potentially terrible issue was directly related to the use of try catch entirely?

Comment: it's completely valid to use a try..catch inside `TransactionScope` which is why I said that is incorrect. Your one specific issue was related to how you implemented them. As a comparison I've had issues converting strings to `DateTime` but I wouldn't advise to `TL;DR: Try to avoid DateTime when using strings`.

Comment: I have thought about this and now believe the issue was related to what was in the try catch and not the try catch itself. I was executing a stored procedure in the function contained w/i the try catch block and the stored procedure failed because of the data passed into it. I assume there's some correlation between the error on db side and the loss of the transactionScope's transaction. Regardless the try catch allowed it to keep going as intended. I will alter the original message w/ the actual situation.